# Database schema with ManyToMany self-referencing relation

Tags: mysql, database-schema

I am designing MySQL database schema and I am not sure if my approach is good enough.

Imagine this situation:

- There are some people
- Each person likes some articles on the internet (Thousands of articles)
- Each article is translated to another language (Tens of languages, can be translated differently on different websites)

I want to be able to specify a name of the article, source language, target language and find all translations of this article. Also I can specify a person and find only articles from his/her "favorites".

**My idea:**

Create 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Language (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE Person (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Article (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `language` INT NOT NULL,
    `person` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`language`) REFERENCES Language (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`person`) REFERENCES Person (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE Relation (
    `article_1` INT NOT NULL,
    `article_2` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`article_1`, `article_2`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`article_1`) REFERENCES Article (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (`article_2`) REFERENCES Article (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Store each article as a record in the table and "connect" them using link table `Relation`.

Each person will create a file with URLs to his/her favorite articles and links to translations:

```
url1_en url1_es url1_de url1_ko
url2_en url2_es url2_de url2_ko
url3_en url3_es url3_de url3_ko
url4_en url4_es url4_de url4_ko
```

Of course, another person can find another German translation for the article `url1_en` and upload it:

```
url1_en url1_es url1_de_2 url1_ko
```

If I will search for `url1_en` with German as target language, I should get `url1_de` and `url_1_de_2`

The problem for me here is how to handle this Self-referencing Many-to-Many relationship of Articles. Also table Relation will grow extremely fast.

Maybe there is a better way to design schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, your approach is ok. I found one error, though. Article should not be tied to person - what, if two persons like same article?

Also, as person may like one article (and not its translation), you can add one more level of complexity. Article is only a container without content, content is in ArticleTranslation table

My proposed schema looks as follows (i focus only on table relationships):

```
Article
  *..* Person [with join table PersonArticle]
  1..* ArticleContent

Person
   *..* Article [with join table PersonArticle]
```

Then, your queries will be as follows (again - pseudocode):

> Find translations

```
SELECT ac2.* FROM Article a
    JOIN ArticleContent ac1
    JOIN ArticleContent ac2 (ac1.Article=ac2.Article)
WHERE ac1.name=<NAME>
   AND ac1.language=<SRC_LANG> 
   AND ac2.language=<TRG_LANG>
```

> Find translations of user favorites

```
SELECT ac2.* 
FROM 
    Person p
    JOIN PersonArticle pa
    JOIN Article a
    JOIN ArticleContent ac1
    JOIN ArticleContent ac2 (ac1.Article=ac2.Article)
WHERE 
   p.id=<PERSON_ID>
   ac1.name=<NAME>
   AND ac1.language=<SRC_LANG> 
   AND ac2.language=<TRG_LANG>
```

**UPDATE** - for really huge number of data, you can consider using some of NoSQL approaches. Some of them are created specially to map such data graphs. This, however, is more complex solution, SQL is good for starters.